# GCP Vertex AI training freeze with matplotlib

Tags: google-cloud-vertex-ai, gcp-ai-platform-training

I am trying to implement custom model training on Vertex AI.

Every time I pushed custom training job to Vertex AI, I could meet the freezing issue in the middle of the process.

The issue occurs in,

```
message: "Generating new fontManager, this may take some time..."
pathname: "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib/font_manager.py"
```

I tried to remove matplotlib package either, but it still tries to setup fontManager during the process.

Is there anyone who've been facing a same issue or have solved before?
Thanks,

I tried to remove all the importing part of matplotlib in the scripts, but it still seems like vertex AI training job tries to install it.

Comment: A bit of context is lacking on your question unfortunately. Could you please give a bit more of context? maybe pasting some code snippets (you don't need to disclose all your code - but initially pasting the parts where matplotlib is called should be useful)

Comment: Is it possible to share your code and errors you are facing.Can you share the documents you are following.

Comment: my apologies for late response. 
I just ran the yolov5 training script with an arguments.
The referred repo. is, https://github.com/ultralytics/yolov5 

The last command in the log is,

Command '['python3', '-m', 'trainer.task', '--workers', '8', '--device', '0', '--batch-size', '32', '--data', 'data/custom_2023.yaml', '--img', '640 640', '--cfg', 'cfg/training/yolov7-custom.yaml', '--weights', 'yolov7_training.pt', '--name', 'train', '--hyp', 'data/hyp.scratch.p5.yaml']'

Comment: Check: https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/13071 what version of matplotlib are you using? I would also suggest you use Python 3.10+.